# Sort correctly by time open

Tags: .net, sorting, datagrid, devexpress

I have a column in a XtraGrid that shows the time elapsed since the record was inserted. I calculate this on the server and returning the time as a string.

The problem is that its not sorted correctly, Please see image how 9 days is more then 23 days...

[image: Sort Problem]

Any idea how to make it in a way the sort would work better?

Comment: Is the value in the cell just text?  Is it data bound?  Looks like it is sorted alphabetically to me.  If the backing value was a real DateTime, it would sort using that instead.

Comment: Are these values originally strings or possibly TimeSpans?

Comment: Currently I calculate that on the server, in the grid I pass in one long string.

Comment: What would be a better approach to do that?

Comment: You should be storing this data in the DB as a DateTime field. This will solve your problem and potentially future issues with using strings to represetnt time values

Comment: @Simon can you explain more in detail please? how can I save '30 Days 2 Hours 21 Min' in a datetime field?

Comment: @Ezi, so in you table you will have a DateTime field. This can be updated to the current time, whenever the user changes that record. Then when you display the data in the grid, you can use an unbound column, and then display the difference between the current time and the time in the DateTime field in the database (essentially a TimeSpan). Using this method will be easier working with the time field, and then you can simply `SELECT * FROM Table Order by DateTimeField` which will sort your table automatically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around this is to store your values in the Database as a int64 as Ticks, therefore you can do sorting on the server side, then on your application side, create TimeSpans from the Ticks and you can handle the [CustomColumnDisplayText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) to display it however you want, ensuring your column is set to sort on Value and not DisplayText.

Example

Within your CustomDisplayText event of your GridView place

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromTicks(e.Value);
e.DisplayText = string.Format("{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes", span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes);
```

Comment: I don't understand how I could display in a grid '1 Day 5 Hour' when the underlining data is a date

Comment: Did you get this sorted Ezi? The idea is your underlying data would be an Int64 (Long). Then within the CustomColumnDisplayText, obtain that number from the eventargs e.Value, plug it into a TimeSpan then you can get it to display '1 Day 5 Hour' by setting the e.DisplayText value. Hope it all went well.

Comment: Nope.. its still not working. can you give me some kind of sample code how I convert a long value to display '1 Day 5 Hour'? thanks

Comment: Yes it absolutely helped a lot, I was waiting to hear that for a month. It's quite simple but some how I wasn't able to figure it out my self. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could sort it on the server as part of your SQL statement (I'm assuming youre getting this out of a DB).  Your other option is to write your own comparison function which would involve parsing the time back into some kind of timespan and sorting on that.

Comment: Sorting on the server is not an option because the user need to have the ability to change the sort.

Comment: Ah, then you're looking at writing a parsing function to parse the text to a timespan.  Alternatively, you could pass the actual timespan back and use it as a hidden column.  You'd have to use some trickery to get the sorting to use your hidden column.

Comment: How would a time span look like?